# Get LIMIT 3 from a selection

Tags: mysql, subquery

please help me with a subquery.
I have 2 tables :

1. visits : id_viz, Data_viz, Medic_id
2. medics : id_med, Nume, Prenume, Specialty

where visits.Medic_id = medics.id_med,

and I need to find the first 3 medics as number of visits for every Specialty, in 2005.

What I succeed to obtain is the number of visits / every Specialty / for every Medic, but i don't know how to find the first 3 from every Specialty :(.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(m.Nume,' ',m.Prenume) AS Medic,
  m.Specialty,
  COUNT(v.Data_viz) AS nrviz
FROM
  visits v
INNER JOIN
  medics m
ON(v.Medic_id=m.id_med)
WHERE
  YEAR(v.Data_viz) = 2005
GROUP BY
  Medic
ORDER BY
  m.Specialty,
  nrviz DESC
```

I have tried with a LIMIT 3, but of course it doesn't work. I think is necessary to use a subquery but I don't know how. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

In other RDBMS  (like PostgreSQL, Oracle or SQL Server) you could solve this elegantly with a **window function** as defined in the SQL standard. But MySQL does not provide this feature.

Example for **PostgreSQL**:

```
SELECT specialty, medic, nrviz
FROM (
    SELECT m.specialty
          ,array_to_string(ARRAY[m.nume,m.prenume], ' ') AS medic
          ,count(v.data_viz) AS nrviz
          ,row_number() OVER (PARTITON BY m.specialty
                              ORDER BY count(v.data_viz) DESC) AS rn
    FROM   visits v
    JOIN   medics m ON (v.medic_id = m.id_med)
    WHERE  year(v.data_viz) = 2005
    GROUP  BY m.specialty, m.nume, m.prenume
    ) x
WHERE  rn <= 3
ORDER  BY specialty, nrviz DESC, medic;
```

In MySQL you will have to substitute with some black magic using session variables like you can find on [this site](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/).

#### Edit:

Top 3 medics for every specialty could look like this **for MySQL** (untested):

```
SELECT x.*
FROM  (SELECT @lim := 3, @spc := '') vars,
    (
    SELECT m.specialty
          ,concat(m.nume,' ',m.prenume) AS medic
          ,count(v.data_viz) AS nrviz
    FROM   visits v
    JOIN   medics m ON (v.medic_id = m.id_med)
    WHERE  year(v.data_viz) = 2005
    GROUP  BY 1, 2
    ORDER  BY 1, 3 DESC
    ) x
WHERE  CASE WHEN @spc <> x.specialty
            THEN @r := @lim
            ELSE @r := @r - 1
       END > 0
AND    (@spc := x.specialty) IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY x.specialty, x.nrviz DESC, x.medic
```

The variable for `specialty` (`@spc`) is initialized to an empty string - this is assuming it **never hold an empty string**. Else initialize to some other impossible value. Also assumes `specialty` to be **NOT NULL**.

This walks through the ordered results of the query and counts down from `@lim` (3), so it only takes the first three medics per specialty (with the highest number of visits). Whenever the specialty changes, the count is reset to `@lim`.

MySQL is sneaking in procedural elements with session variables into set-based SQL this way. I call that black magic, but it should get the job done.

Comment: Thanks for you effort, but after I try your code, i've received an error : "[Err] 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_romanian_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'" I have to tell you that i have used utf8_romanian when I create the schema. I've need these feature because I use some special Romanian characters :(

Comment: I recreate the schema and use a unitar COLLATE. The code run's now but i received the same result with my code : "What I succeed to obtain is the number of visits / every Specialty / for every Medic, but i don't know how to find the first 3 from every Specialty" :(

Comment: @GabrielMandu: unless I have a mistake in my code, the second query should give you only the top three (highest count) per medic and specialty. Ahhh .. I guess you want the top 3 medics per specialty, right? Coming right up ...

Comment: yeap, i need the top 3 medics per specialty

Comment: @GabrielMandu: I think understand what you are after now. I adjusted both queries to yield the top 3 medics per specialty ranked by the count of visits.

Comment: Did you edit your answer with the new code, because I've tried it, and **it gives me the same result**, not top 3 / per specialty ranked by the count of visits ! :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what your query would look like with a subquery:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(m.Nume,' ',m.Prenume) AS Medic,
  m.Specialty,
COUNT(v.Data_viz) AS nrviz
FROM
  visits v
INNER JOIN
  medics m
ON(v.Medic_id=m.id_med)
WHERE
YEAR(v.Data_viz) = (SELECT...)
GROUP BY
  Medic
ORDER BY
  m.Specialitate,
  nrviz DESC
```

The thing to know about subqueries is that they are executed before your main query,

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think that my question was not so clear. What I want to obtain is "the first 3 medics as number of visits for every Specialty, in 2005". Regarding the subquery it's my supposition that this report can be made through a subquery. I didn't need a subquery for to select a different year. Hope now it's clear. Thanks anyway